Unable to view Email templates in salesforce developer edition
I am unable to view the salesforce email templates in the setup. Please refer the below screenshot:

I am using developer edition of salesforce and I am unable to find the email templates.

Does this answer your question? Do not see "Classic Email Template" option in Setup

Please follow the steps mentioned in this link.

Do you have Manage Public Lightning Email Templates permission enabled?

Can you check and confirm which profile is assigned to the login user?
